# How to checkout only one branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

We have two Git branches, dev and master.  Both are in stash.  When starting, I was on the local copy of the master branch.  I ran Git checkout dev to switch to the dev branch then wanted to check what updates will flow in if I do a Git pull so I ran:

```
git fetch
```

but despite me being on the dev branch, fetch downloaded objects and refs for both dev and master!  I expected it would do so for only the current branch:

```
tom@saltmstr:/opt/salt $ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 67, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
remote: Total 67 (delta 44), reused 15 (delta 7)
Unpacking objects: 100% (67/67), done.
From git+ssh://stash.mds.xyz:7999/mds/salt
   3ec937f..f53d944  dev        -> origin/dev
   f4b87bb..3d17dd5  master     -> origin/master
tom@saltmstr:/opt/salt $ git fetch
```

What would be the correct syntax for Git fetch and Git pull to bring in changes only to the dev branch?

```
git fetch -b dev ?
git pull -b dev ?
```

or would it be:

```
git fetch -b dev origin/dev?
git pull -b dev origin/dev?
```

I couldn't find anything about ONLY checking out a specific branch using either fetch or pull so I'm posting the question.

Comment: This action is just synchronizing the remote repository with your local repository.

Comment: I only need to synchronize the local dev with the remote dev.  How to do this?  I don't want to sync master at this time.

Comment: You can do `git pull origin dev` assuming your remote is referenced as `origin` and your branch is `dev`.

Comment: Kool, ty.  Likewise if I do a `git fetch origin dev` will it only affect the dev branch unlike my earlier attempt that fetched for both dev and master?

Comment: Should behave the same way

Comment: Might want to have a look at [this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?rq=1)

Comment: `git fetch origin dev` didn't work.  I can clearly see the branches when I type `git branch -a` however:

` # git branch -a|grep -Ei "master|dev"
* dev
  master
  origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: Sorry just saw your second comment.  I did go through that link but haven't seen the specific reference to what I wanted.  I'm going through it again.  I basically get:

`"The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it."`

Comment: I don't understand. If `git pull origin dev` works, then `git fetch origin dev` must work also. The only difference is it doesn't merge with your working changes in the latter case (fetch).

Comment: Neither do I.  What is the command syntax you use for both?  Let me follow your working one and see.

Comment: If you go to [this link](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=local_repo;) and click on the 'Upstream Repository' you will see that git pull and git fetch largely have the same syntax. The commands I listed in my earlier comment are the ones I use (except I have `develop` instead of `dev` as my develop branch).

Comment: Thanks guy's.  I was able to get things going with these tips.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefspecarefspec) to let Git know which remote ref maps to which local ref:

```
git fetch origin dev:origin/dev
```